# How to define respObj?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am bit stack in this issue. If "subfolders" is targeting sub folders and "subswfs" target swf files what is the right property to target html files? subhtmls doesn't work.

```
success : function( respObj, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
            if ( 'undefined' !== typeof(respObj['status']) ) {
                if ( 
                        ('success' === respObj['status']) && 
                        ('undefined' !== typeof(respObj['folders'])) && 
                        ('undefined' !== typeof(respObj['swfs'])) )
```

**EDIT SOLUTION**

"subshtmls" this is the right format

Comment: are you using q library ? or external file?? where is `respObj` defined ?

Comment: have a look on my edit